# How do I trigger an event when a button is clicked on a user profile?

Tags: 7, users, hooks

Let's say I want to make a bunch of nodes based on what's in a specific field when someone clicks a button on their user profile.

Is this possible with a custom built module? And if so what hook would I use to display that button on the user profile, and how would I get it to call a custom function on click?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes a custom module could accomplish this. I'd use drupal's [form api](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21topics%21forms_api_reference.html/7) to create a simple form and output it to a block that you display on user profile pages. The code below should get you started.

Create the form. The hidden element is grabbing the users id from the url.

```
function my_module_form($form, &$form_state) {
  $form = array();

  $form['uid'] = array(
    '#type' => 'hidden', 
    '#value' => arg(1),
  );

  $form['submit'] = array(
    '#type' => 'submit',
    '#value' => 'Submit',
  );

  return $form;
}

function my_module_form_submit($form, &$form_state) {
  $uid = $form_state['values']['uid'];
  // do some stuff
}
```

Now use [hook_block_info](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_info/7) and [hook_block_view](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21block%21block.api.php/function/hook_block_view/7) to create a new block containing your form.

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_block_info().
 */
function my_module_block_info() {
  $blocks['my_module'] = array(
    'info' => t('My Name'),
  );
  return $blocks;
}

/**
 * Implementation of hook_block_view().
 */
function my_module_block_view($delta='') {
  $block = array();
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'my_module':
      $block['subject'] = t('My Title');
      $my_form = drupal_get_form('my_module_form');
      $block['content'] = drupal_render($my_form);

      break;
  }
  return $block;
}
```

Here's an article on creating a module in D7 if you are not familiar with how to do that. http://www.justinphelan.com/post/how-write-your-own-module-drupal-7

Answer (score 0):

Wow, this is a question with many solutions. Some stuff I can quickly think of:

**Developers** way:

1. create a custom module: https://www.drupal.org/developing/modules/7
2. implement [hook_menu](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7) to create callbacks for your links
3. implement your logic in the callback functions defined for your entries in hook_menu.
4. "presentation layer". Depending on the structure of your website and your profiles:

   a) Create a block with your links in it, references: [block_example](https://api.drupal.org/api/examples/block_example!block_example.module/7), [link function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7)

   b) Implement a ["pseudo field"](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.api.php/function/hook_field_extra_fields/7) on fieldable entities (e.g. user, profile2)

   c) Use [link function](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/l/7) in your profile template file e.g. [user-profile.tpl.php](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!user!user-profile.tpl.php/7)

extra points might be awarded if you use the link function and your hook menu implementation together with the ajax framework. [example](https://www.drupal.org/node/2046693).

**Site builders** way (one way.. there are many):

1. create a [flag](https://www.drupal.org/project/flag)
2. create a [rule](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) for flagging items
3. in that rule implement your logic
4. optional: undo the flagging (so the user can do this action again)

All of the mentioned solutions will probably require some logic for **handling the access and display** of that button as well.

(one) **developer way**, if this button appears on user/id:

```
<?php
global $user;    
if (arg(0) == 'user' && arg(1) == $user->uid && null === arg(2) {
  print l('do something', 'yourcallballback/' . arg(1));
}
```

**site builders** way (for the example from above):

usually there's no additional access check required here, you can setup that flag to be global and only clickable once if you want to make sure that it's only available once. for the display part you probably really have to use code to only show that flag if the current user visits his own profile.